# Understanding proof of p.527, Proposition 3 in the Cox's ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the David A. Cox's Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms, p.527, Proposition 3 and stuck at some statement.

First, I arrange associated notions.

Suppose $p = (p_1, \dots , p_n) \in k^n$. If $\alpha = (\alpha_1 , \dots , \alpha_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}^{n}$, let

$$(x-p)^{\alpha}:= ( x_1-p_1)^{\alpha_1}\cdots(x_n-p_n)^{\alpha_n}$$ and note that $(x-p)^{\alpha}$ has total degree $|\alpha| = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n$. Now, given any polynomial $f\in k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ of total degree $d$, we can write $f$ as a polynomial in $x_i - p_i$, so that $f$ is $k$-linear combination of $(x-p)^{\alpha}$ for $|\alpha| \le d$. If we group according to total degree, we can write

$$ f= f_{p,0} + f_{p,1} + \cdots + f_{p,d} ,$$

where $f_{p,j}$ is a $k$-linear combination of $(x-p)^{\alpha}$ for $|\alpha|=j$.

We can now define the tangent cone.

*Definition*. Let $V\subseteq k^n$ be an affine variety and let $p=(p_1, \dots, p_n) \in V$.

(i) If $f\in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is a nonzero polynomial, then $f_{p,\min}$ is defined to be $f_{p,j}$, where $j$ is the smallest integer such that $f_{p,j} \neq 0$ in $ f= f_{p,0} + f_{p,1} + \cdots + f_{p,d} $

(ii) The **tangent cone of $V$ at $p$**, denoted by $C_p(V)$, is the variety

$$ C_p(V) = V(f_{p, \min} | f\in I(V)).$$

Second, I state p.527 Proposition 3 in his book and present proof

**Proposition 3.** Let $p\in V\subseteq k^n$. Then $C_p(V)$ is the translate of the affine cone of a variety in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}(k)$.

**Here, I explain the term 'affine cone ( c.f. his book p.411 )' as follows.** Let $I$ be a homogeneous ideal in $k[x_0, \dots , x_n]$. The ideal $I$ gives us the projective variety $V=V(I) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^{n}(k)$. Then we call $C_V := V_a(I) \subseteq k^{n+1}$ the *affine cone of $V$.* Note that $C_V$ uses the same ideal $I$, but now we look for solutions in the affine space $k^{n+1}$.

*Proof of Proposition 3.* Introduce new coordinates on $k^n$ by letting $X_i = x_i - p_i$. Relative to this coordinate system, we can assume that $p$ is the origin $0$. Then $f_{0, \min}$ is a homogeneous polynoimal in $X_1, \dots , X_n$, and **as $f$ varies over $I(V)$, the $f_{0, \min}$ generate a homogeneous ideal $J\subseteq k[X_1, \dots , X_n]$.** Then $C_p(V) = V_a(J) \subseteq k^n$ by definition. Since $J$ is homogeneous, we also get a projective variety $W=V_p(J) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^{n-1}(k)$, and as we saw in Chapter 8 ( c.f. above explanation about affine cones ), this means that $C_p(V)$ is an affine cone $C_W \subseteq k^n$ of $W$. This proves the proposition.

I am trying to understand the bold statement in the proof. Let $I(V) = \langle f_1 \dots, f_s \rangle$ be finte generator by the Hilbert basis theorem.

Perhaps,

$$ J:= \langle f_{0,\min} : f\in I(V) \rangle = \langle f_{i,0, \min} : 1 \le i \le s \rangle$$ ?

If so, then since the ideal generated by finite homogeneous polynomials is homogeneous ideal ( c.f. his book, p.407, Theorem 2 ), we obtain that $J$ is homogeneous ideal. Why the bold statement is true? Where the condition "$f$ varies over $I(V)$" is used? Can anyone helps?